# How can I convert multible rows to a single row by ID in R

Tags: r, row

As you can see here, I have 2 + 2 + 1 rows which have the same ID. I would like to convert the rows which have the same ID to one single row.

```
          ID INVENT_KPV KASVUKOHA_KOOD RINDE_KOOD PUULIIGI_KOOD VANUS
297945203711 2009.08.31             MO          1            KS    60
297945203711 2009.08.31             MO          2            KU    50
297945303711 2009.08.31             SS          1            MA    60
297945303711 2009.08.31             SS          1            KS    60
297945403711 2009.08.31             JO          1            HB    NA
```

It should look like this (I also don't need the additional date and "KASVUKOHA_KOOD" there because when the ID is the same, then the date and "KASVUKOHA_KOOD" is also the same)

```
          ID INVENT_KPV KASVUKOHA_KOOD RINDE_KOOD PUULIIGI_KOOD VANUS  RINDE_KOOD PUULIIGI_KOOD VANUS
297945203711 2009.08.31             MO          1            KS    60           2            KU    50
297945303711 2009.08.31             SS          1            MA    60           1            KS    60
297945403711 2009.08.31             JO          1            HB    NA
```

As you may understood already, I don't know how to do this. I'd appreciate if you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)#1.9.7+
res <- dcast(setDT(df1), ID+INVENT_KPV +KASVUKOHA_KOOD~rowid(KASVUKOHA_KOOD),
                             value.var = c("RINDE_KOOD", "PUULIIGI_KOOD", "VANUS"))
#         ID INVENT_KPV KASVUKOHA_KOOD RINDE_KOOD_1 RINDE_KOOD_2 PUULIIGI_KOOD_1 PUULIIGI_KOOD_2 VANUS_1 VANUS_2
#1: 297945203711 2009.08.31             MO            1            2              KS              KU      60      50
#2: 297945303711 2009.08.31             SS            1            1              MA              KS      60      60
#3: 297945403711 2009.08.31             JO            1           NA              HB              NA      NA      NA

res1 <- res[, c(1:3, order(as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", names(res)[-(1:3)])))+3), with = FALSE]
setnames(res1, sub("_\\d+$", "", names(res1)))[]
#        ID INVENT_KPV KASVUKOHA_KOOD RINDE_KOOD PUULIIGI_KOOD VANUS RINDE_KOOD PUULIIGI_KOOD VANUS
#1: 297945203711 2009.08.31             MO          1            KS    60          2            KU    50
#2: 297945303711 2009.08.31             SS          1            MA    60          1            KS    60
#3: 297945403711 2009.08.31             JO          1            HB    NA         NA            NA    NA
```

Comment: Thank you! But this wasn't the result I need because the order is messed up now. :/

Comment: @M.P.  Are you concerned about the column order because I don't find any difference between this and expected output. Then, it can be easily changed.

Comment: Yes, I really need the order to be this: id, invent_kpv, kasvukoha_kood, rinde_kood, puuliigi_kood, vanus and then again rinde_kood, puuliigi_kood, vanus and so on.
It would be also great if they wouldn't have the number 1,2 or 3 (eg. rinde_kood_1) but I'm guessing it's impossible.

Simply put, it would be awesome if I could just "copy" the rows next to each other if they have the same ID.

Comment: @M.P.  Create a vector of names that you wanted in that order and then do `res1 <- res[, vecNames]`. Regarding removing the suffix, it can be done, but it makes things complicated when you try to get a column as column names are duplicated

Comment: I'm a beginner, so could you say what exactly I have to do? How can I create a vector of names?